# Why aren't ticket release dates published?

Tags: live-music

I notice that on almost all ticket websites, they never publish the date the tickets will become available. Is that because they are trying to deter scalpers? This is even true for Broadway show sites and the like. How are fans supposed to find out when tickets become available for sale?

Comment: Check back every day; join the fan club; listen to the radio.

Comment: Are you talking about sites like Ticketmaster?  Because I've never seen a show that *didn't* have on-sale dates (including fan club, promotional and general public dates).  At this point, most of the big North American tours are in full swing, but if you can find an event that's not on sale yet you should be able to [open their page](http://www.ticketmaster.com/scorpions-50th-anniversary-tour-with-special-santa-barbara-california-10-06-2015/event/09004E6202035F00?artistid=736062&majorcatid=10001&minorcatid=1&tm_link=search_msg-0_09004E6202035F00) and look for the link for "Onsale Times".